# AS3: Are events inefficient?

Tags: actionscript-3

Alright, obviously using event handling is fantastically convenient, but obviously the same effects can be achieved through composition as well.  Just as I can dispatch an event to be received in the context of another object, I can include that other object and manipulate it directly.

Now, the event-driven approach is certainly more organized.  I'm trying to optimize a program that I'm seeing some performance issues with though, and wondering how far eliminating the use of events might take me.  Any guiding wisdom is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

The reason Events have a reputation for being inefficient is because:

- Constructing objects is considered slow.
- A *new* Event object is constructed every time something dispatches an event.

In a scenario where you have many objects dispatching many events, this obviously gives the result of many, many `Event` objects being constructed each frame.

With this information, you can easily retain the convenience of the Event Model while greatly mitigating the construction of Event objects. Some approaches could include:

- Implement object pooling for Event objects.
- Create and use a single instance for Events which aren't meaningful enough to need independence, or where the instance will not be needed in more than one place at one time.

These approaches obviously involve you creating your own event model, and can't impact the way the existing model works with inbuilt objects.

Comment: By object pooling, do you mean to create a series of Event objects that will be used and just recycle the same objects over and over?  If so, would you recommend holding them in a static constant, say, in some sort of helper class or in the class to be using them?

Comment: @JS The general idea is to create a `Pool` class which will maintain a list of 'recycled' objects. The pool defines the maximum pool size, and has a getter which will either return an object from the pool, or create a new one and return that if the pool is empty.

Comment: That makes sense.  Would you recommend using a vector as an instance variable and having a unique Pool class for each data type to be stored, and that way using the maximum size you mentioned you could just shift the bottom element out and maintain a maximum memory usage?

Comment: @JS I wouldn't make the maximum size anything excessive, it only needs to be enough to cover what you would expect to be the upper limit of concurrent events being dispatched.

Answer (score 0):

You should check out Signals.
https://github.com/robertpenner/as3-signals

Comment: That looks nice syntactically, but where is the performance gain?

Comment: Check out few pages. [Signals vs Events](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=as3+signals+vs+events&rlz=1C1CHFX_en-GBGB536GB536&oq=as3+events+ver&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0j69i60l3.9443j0j7&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8)

Comment: Also just using callback functions, depending on the situation.  I've used both.